# Hide empty console window in a all GUI Powershell script?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have made a very simple Powershell script with WinForms GUI.
Everything works as intended but, when I run the .ps1 script with PowerShell a black empty console window appears at first and then the GUI shows.

Anyway to make the console window dissapear?

Best regards

Comment: How do you start your script?

Comment: Also: do you want window to disappear at some point (pretty easy to do) or don't appear at all (never had need to find a way and honestly, don't know if it even exists).

Comment: I am assuming that you are double cliking on the PS1 script. Is that correct? Also, sample code would really help in giving an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [small article on this subject](http://www.silogix.fr/Blog-Silogix/powershell-ne-sait-pas-demarrer-sans-afficher-une-fenetre.aspx) (sorry in french) one year ago.

Here is the common solution using a small VBS script to start PowerShell hidding his window (the trick is in the last **,0**).

```
Set Args = Wscript.Arguments
'MsgBox  "Chemin LDAP: " & Args(0)
'MsgBox  "Classe: " & Args(1)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -Noninteractive -file c:\SlxRH\RhModif.ps1 " & chr(34) & Args(0) & chr(34) , 0
```

I also embeded PowerShell in an executable with no console called [slxPShell2.EXE](http://www.silogix.fr/developpement/outils/Ressources-PowerShell/menu-contextuel-windows-explorer-full-powershell.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I found the above didn't work for me. I used this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "CMD /C START /B " & objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%") & "\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file " & "YourScript.ps1", 0, False

Set objShell = Nothing
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This solution Minimizes Powershell window after it starts.  Powershell window opens, then disapears, without using any outside code.  Put at beginning of your script.

```
$t = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $t -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```

Comment: Note that if you want to show the window again later, you need to save its handle while it is still visible. So I do `$hWindow = (Get-Process -id $pid).MainWindowHandle` (also, shortened the code to get current process a little) only once early in my script, and pass that variable as the first `ShowWindow` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got this working:

1. Have the Winforms GUI script in one ScriptOne.ps1 file
2. Create another LaunchScriptOne.ps1 file with the content:

`powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\path\to\ScriptOne.ps1"`.

The solution was provided in another thread on the same topic: [Hide or Minimize the powershell prompt after Winform Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922745/hide-or-minimize-the-powershell-prompt-after-winform-launch)

I hope someone will find a way to put this into one single script as well. The answers above in this thread did not help me, but maybe I did something wrong, idk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nube so no rep so can't comment inline... though wrt @Ipse's solution which I'm a fan of, I also make sure to close the hidden window when the script is done... not sure if PS gets around to this sort of auto-garbage collection, but suspect it's good best practice.

eg. at end of your script I'd suggest doing:

stop-process -Id $PID

(which should terminate that hidden window v. just leave it lurking around and tying up those resources).