# Hide or Minimize the powershell prompt after Winform Launch

Tags: powershell

I have written a simple powershell script to launch a winform(Winform code written within powershell script for example showContent.ps1 file) & showing some content.
I need to hide the powershell.exe command prompt after the launch of the Winform.

After searching some cases in web, I tried below Scenario:
1)I tried to execute "**powershell.exe -Command -windowstyle Hidden**" in the start of the script file "showContent.ps1"

2) Created a new script file exa:LaunchWinForm.ps1 and in that mentioned the command as:
**PowerShell.exe -windowstyle Hidden showContent.ps1**

It is not working.

**I am using Powershell 3.0**

Could anyone tell what is going wrong or suggest any way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new separate script file you created, try this:

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File "c:\path\to the\GUI_Script.ps1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution Minimizes Powershell window after it starts. Powershell window opens, then disapears, without using any outside code. I put at beginning of my scripts, but sounds like you want to put the code after you open your form.

```
$t = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $t -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```